# Is it possible to partition tables with JetBrains DataGrip? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

Short and sweet, as the title states: is it possible to create table partitions with DataGrip?

Comment: Doesn't it allow you to run arbitrary `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah i guess you can specify in the code how you create the table but i was hoping some kind of automatic way to create multiple table partitions

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create partition tables in DataGrip UI.

You can create them in console and view it in database tree view. IDE supports partitions for PostgreSQL and Greenplum database.

[image: partition tables]